# How to give all users the ability to view a base data set. And allowing them to add their own data entries to view and share to users

Tags: python, django, database, user-input, web-frameworks

Just a heads up, I am new to using web frameworks. My only experience so far comes from completing the [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django), [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) and [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django) tutorials. But I'm making my way through [these](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials) along with my own project.

I'm creating a web app that has an "official" database table that all website/app users can view. But, I want to be able to let them add their own data entries to the table, which only they can view and edit. And would be able to grant other users/friends access to their created data entries, to expand the total number of entries made available. Without making everyone using the site having to work out which data entries are the "official" and which are user created.

[Hopefully a better way of understanding what I'm planning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyBCr.jpg)
[image]

So, what would be the best method for setting up user accounts to have access to the main database table and their own data set, which they can grant access for others to view?

Would this mean creating a table for each user, and if so how can this be set up automatically upon account creation?
I've read that creating a new table in the database can be cumbersome later on if lots of accounts with their own tables of data are created.

I've looked through the Django documentation, but it seems to be more focussed on user account creation and authorisation. And regarding databases, I can't find any questions/posts that relate to what I'm trying to make. Especially with creating a personal list of data entries for each user upon account creation.

Thank you, for taking the time to read this, even if you don't have an answer!

Comment: You may want to look into creating custom models and relationships in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/ . Welcome to SO!